# How to put criterion into sumif in excel?

Tags: excel

I have workbook containing two sheets,

```
Sheet1:
A      B 
Income Score
100     90
200     80
...     ...
Sheet2:
A      B
Sum    Filter
?      85
```

I want to count the sum of Income with Score larger than 85, where 85 is store in B2, 
I can only do

```
=sumifs(Sheet1!A2:A3, Sheet1!B2:B3, ">=85")
```

How can I pass the B2 cell into the criterion? Something like:

```
=sumifs(Sheet1!A2:A3, Sheet1!B2:B3, ">=B2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=sumifs(Sheet1!A2:13, Sheet1!B2:B3, ">="&B2)
```

If you keep the `B2` inside the quotes (""), it will think you want everything greater than the actual **value** B2, instead of the **value of** B2 (i.e. 85)
The ampersand links the operator (">=") and the value together

Answer (score 0):

The formula you want is:

```
=sumifs(Sheet1!A2:A3, Sheet1!B2:B3, ">=" & B2)
```

If the cell is inside the brackets it thinks you are referring to the literal string "B2" and not a cell.